# Как правильно поставить запятые: "вперёд и ни шагу назад"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Вперёд, - и ни шагу назад!

или

> Вперёд, и ни шагу назад!

или

> Вперёд и ни шагу назад!

Answer (score 3):

Вперёд и ни шагу назад!
Строго по правилам - не нужно никаких знаков, потому что это два восклицательных предложения (как верно уловил Варяг-91). Запятая между частями сложносоч. предлож. не ставится, если имеется общий член, общая интонация - вопросительная или восклицательная,между назывными и безличными с синонимами. Обычно в такой фразе есть и общая частица "только": Только вперёд и ни шагу назад!

Однако если хочется добавить экспрессии,разделить части предложения, можно поставить тире, но это будет уже интонационный знак.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, здесь надо написать так: "Вперед - и ни шагу назад!"

Answer (score 0):

**Вперед! И ни шагу назад!**   Вот так в самый раз!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже написал "Вперед - и ни шагу назад!"

Ваши же варианты как-то не очень понятны.

Запятая после "вперед" ничем не мотивирована, тем более - в сочетании с тире.
Но совсем без знака там плохо. Остаётся тире - на основании правила противопоставления. Или неожиданного сочетания.

То, что Варяг предлагает - возможно, конечно, но это уже другая грамматика.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, я поставил бы тире в таком варианте: "Вперёд и - ни шагу назад!" После "и" напрашивается продолжение фразы, например, "...с  песнями!". Но само слово "вперёд", энергичное, требовательное, призывное должно сопровождаться не менее энергичным, деятельным словом или словосочетанием. Полная фраза без тире скучна, не может внушить слушателям (читателям!) собственной энергетики. Считаю вариант [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus) вполне приемлемым, хотя я объяснил причины того, почему переместил тире в другое место. Тире здесь, скорее, не знак препинания,а знак эмоционального выражения чувств пишущего, которые в узкие рамки правил правописания вместить трудно. Уже отмечалось, что постановка знака препинания перед "и" тут не требуется. Всё дело в эмоциях. Ставить тире перед "и", на мой взгляд, эмоционально упрощает, обедняет пропагандистскую силу призыва. Последующая часть фразы должна быть более значимой, чем первая, и на это надо обязательно обратить внимание, поставив тире после "и", потому что "и" отвлекает внимание читателя (слушателя), является как бы порогом, бруствером, который надо преодолеть, прежде чем бежать вперёд... Тяжко ворочаю слова. Как камни. Не каждому дано быть убедительным. Поймёте ли, что я хотел сказать?